# About accessing only through mage.php to generate json output

Tags: blocks, model, controllers, external

I want to disable the frontend and backend Magento web access temporarily and generate json output from the existing database content.

1. Am I right when assuming controllers and blocks are not called when doing that?
2. For a beginner in Magento and PHP in general, what are tips and tricks to find the elements needed to write Magento code when accessing externally just to use the existing business logic (it's not needed to extend it). Do you think I should study the content of blocks and controllers to find out how the different types of models are used to do all the main store processing?
3. Just out of curiosity, can I have the Magento installation out of the root web directory?

Answer (score 0):

1. you could still instantiate controllers or blocks and do sth. with it, but basically you are right saying that a controller is normally called from a http request and the layout and blocks are generated when a specific controller is executed.
2. - if you want to use magento business logic in an external system, you should access it over the api http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html
   - if you just want to use the framework you should take a look at the lib/Varien folder
   - if you just want to mess around with magento you could create a shell script https://www.codementor.io/tips/3771824132/how-to-create-a-shell-script-in-magento-1-x
   - if you want to use the models without doing it over the api you still have in most cases to bootstrap the whole magento application. You could look in the index.php, cron.php or api.php for hints on that
3. sure, you just can't access it over the webserver. Cronjobs and Shellscripts for example would still work

Comment: actually if you just want to use some magento business logic and don't want to use the whole framework i just found this presentation really nice as a starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rcq9vOgS-Ao